# In the heroku cli how to I run commands (e.g. rails c) on pipeline apps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, command-line-interface, heroku-cli

I'm collaborating on an organization and all of our apps are in a pipeline.

If I list apps on my account there are no apps.

If I list pipelines there is one, for example `somecompanyname`. On the heroku dashboard this pipeline has 17 apps, for example `release-candidate`.

How do I run commands via the heroku cli agaist these apps, for example `rails c` against one of the pipeline apps.

I can't see any commands in the cli help for accsessing pipeline speisific apps, or how to list any of them.

I want to run something like `heroku run rails c --app release-candidate --pipeline somecompanyname` but I don't know what the correct command is, and can't find it in search results for docs too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is litrally just: `heroku run rails c --app release-candidate`, the app is there it's just not on the app list when requested.